# Using Google signup API how do I get a user's phone number?

Tags: php, google-api

I need the user contact number when any user signup through Google account on my website.
I am using following code to fetch the user’s information from Google.
By using this code I am able to get the user's all information except his phone number.
Is it possible to get the user phone number and if so how?

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId(*******************);
    $client->setClientSecret(*******************);
    $client->setRedirectUri(*******************);
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts"); 
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly");
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read");
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly");
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user");
    $client->addScope("email");
    $client->addScope("profile");
    $service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
    $data = $service->userinfo->get();
```